# Doctrine Serializer : Problem on using groups

Tags: laravel, symfony, serialization, doctrine-orm

I'm using symfony serializer for my entities and there is no problem unless whenever I try to use groups on my entity properties I get this error :

```
 [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups" in property 
 App\Entities\User::$id was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this 
 annotation?
```

Here is my entity :

```
namespace App\Entities;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping AS ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
   /**
    * @ORM\Id
    * @Groups("user_show")
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $id;

   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string")
    */
    protected $password;
}
```

And I have this code in my `AppServiceProvider` (I'm using Laravel)

```
public function boot()
{

    $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AnnotationLoader(new AnnotationReader()));
    $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()];
    $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory)];

    $this->app->bind(SerializerInterface::class, function () use ($normalizers, $encoders) {
        return new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem by registering symfony annotations for laravel doctrine
More info [here](https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm/issues/442)